# How to scroll pallet horizontally when i Next and Prev button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am newbie to development. I want to scroll my question pallet Up and Down according to the question number when i click next and previous buttons.

[image: Image attached here]

My pallet div contains more than 200 questions (dynamically). Sometimes it has less than 200 questions.

Below is my minimal code:

Under my next button i have write following function

```
function next(id) {

if (id >= 40 && id < 79) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 370}, 'fast');
}
if (id > 80 && id < 119) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 740}, 'fast');
}
if (id > 120 && id < 159) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 1110}, 'slow');
}
if (id >= 160 && id < 200) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 1480}, 'slow');
}
if (id >= 200 && id < 240) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 1850}, 'slow');
}
if (id >= 240 && id < 300) {
    $(".question-container").animate({scrollTop: 2220}, 'slow');
}
```

Anyone could you able to help me?

Thanks
Thangavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be use the `window.scrollTo()` after detecting the top position of your target element.

```js
function goTo(item) {
  var top = document.getElementById(item).offsetTop;
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
}
```

```css
p {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goTo('one')">Scrol to element</button>
<p></p>
<div id="one">one element</div>
```

As alternative you could use a jQuery plugin as "carousel". There are many online, mine own version is available here if you are interesting to give it a try:
https://github.com/gibbok/jquery-slidertv

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 window.scrollBy(0, 10);
```

in javascript to scroll by 10px downwards.You can adjust accordingly the pixel by which u need to scroll.
Reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp)